# Running GRASS GIS from PyCharm

Tags: python, grass-gis, pycharm, pygrass

I follow the [Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly) with GRASS 7.8.8 (2023), but it did not work as intended. The Python line "gs.message" runs, but the line "gs.run_command('g.region', flags='p')" give me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gparada\PycharmProjects\grass_proj\main.py", line 53, in <module>
    gs.run_command('g.region', flags='p') 
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 441, in run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 342, in handle_errors
    raise CalledModuleError(module=None, code=code,
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None g.region -p ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 3221225785. See errors in the (error) output.
```

I didn't find useful information online to solve my error. My code is:

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gisbase = r'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8'
    gisdb = r'C:\GRASS'
    python_path = r'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\etc\python'
    location = 'epsg_32718'
    mapset = 'PERMANENT'

    #other routes
    bin_path = r'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\bin'
    lib_path = 'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\lib'
    extrabin_path = r'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\extrabin'
    python39_path = r'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\Python39'
    script_path = r'C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\scripts'

    # Append to path
    sys.path.append(python_path)
    sys.path.append(bin_path)
    sys.path.append(lib_path)
    sys.path.append(extrabin_path)
    sys.path.append(python39_path)
    sys.path.append(script_path)

    # Set GISBASE environment variable
    os.environ['GISBASE'] = gisbase
    os.environ['GISDBASE'] = gisdb

    print(sys.path)

    import grass.script as gs
    import grass.script.setup as gsetup


    ###########
    # launch session
    rcfile = gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)
    gs.message('Current GRASS GIS 7 environment:')   # WORKS

    gs.run_command('g.region', flags='p')  # DONT WORK
    # delete the rcfile
    os.remove(rcfile)
```

Comment: Hint: Please consider to use the way more modern version GRASS GIS 8.3 (see https://grass.osgeo.org/download/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try the instructions for PyCharm on the GRASS wiki:
https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tools_for_Python_programming#PyCharm_IDE

Comment: Hello Anna, i first look that link but i did not find the "python-grass79.bat" or equivalent in my grass gis folder.

Comment: I guess this should read `python-grass78.bat`. Can you please see if that file is there? If you used OSGeo4W to install then it might be here: `C:\\OSGeo4W64\bin\python-grass78.bat`

Comment: I install the last version of QGIS that comes with grass 8.3.0 and i found the python-grass83.bat in the location that markusN point it, Thanks Anna and @markusN.

Comment: Wiki page also updated.